Find a Group Policy by its Folder Id
This site contains a Windows (GPO) subsection in almost every section. This subsection contains Group Policy Folder Ids, like these:

Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\AllowedDomainsForApps
Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\AllowFileSelectionDialogs
Software\Policies\Mozilla\Firefox\AppAutoUpdate

Where do you find these settings to check or modify their values? Via GUI/PowerShell/other.
GPResult calls these paths in its output Folder Id's, literally.
